# Eclipse Just Crashes (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, java, php, crash, eclipse

This is crazy. Eclipse keeps crashing, closing itself a few seconds after I start it and I have no reason why. I have tried everything that I have seen here and nothing helps. I am so desperate that I think of going back to Windows and not use Linux. I need eclipse for my work.

I tried to remove eclipse and Install it again. I did the:

```
   apt-get autoremove eclipse* --purge
```

I downloaded latest eclipse LUNA version.
I deleted my workspace. I have deleted the project and created it again. I have changed the eclipse.ini and included a -debug line and run eclipse from command line with ./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState

Still - nothing works - It keeps crashes.

I do think it have something to do with PHP PDT plugin, because it crashes much faster when I work on some of the classes in PHP rather than I just work on HTML.

The problem is there is nothing in serious in the log or in the output. I do have some minor things, attached here. There isn't a better log ?

I am using Xubuntu 14.04, OracleJDK-8, Eclipse LUNA with Java and PDT

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/xxx/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.0.20140606-0033.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2901Mhz, 15954MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2901Mhz, 15954MB
[000:000] Computer model: Not available
[000:001] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:001] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:001] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2901Mhz, 15954MB

[000:001] Computer model: Not available
[000:001] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:001] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:001] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:003] Warning(optionsfile.cc:30): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:003] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:004] Cpu: 6.60.3, x4, 2901Mhz, 15954MB
[000:004] Computer model: Not available
```

I will appreciate any help.